# Notepad++ PHP Syntax Autocomplete

Tags: php, autocomplete, notepad++

I have added following lines at start of %PRPOGRA~%\Notepad++\plugin\APIs\php.xml

```
<KeyWord name="$_GET"></KeyWord>
<KeyWord name="$_POST"></KeyWord>
<KeyWord name="$_SERVER"></KeyWord>
```

CTRL+Space to generate autocomplete syntax list for

```
$_GET
$_POST
$_SERVER
```

List should be appeared on pressing $ (shift + 4).

Comment: Not answering your question, but I've wrestled with Notepad++ 's autocomplete before and I would suggest that if you ever get the time you might want to look into NetBeans instead.

Comment: @Manos Dilaverakis or PHPEclipse

Comment: i have seen into phpeclipse, netbean, dreamviewer, phpcoder all ...

Comment: i found Notepad++ is best single application that each programmer must have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found a hint for my own question.
>   Notepad++ generate AutoCompletion list of syntax, only on keypress event of
>   A-Z or a-z. 
>   You can modify it behavior by modifying files at

```
 NotePad++ > plugin > APIs > *.xml
```

`<keyword name="anything">` keyword tags must be sort by attribute value "name" and this sorting is ASCII code wise,

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you ever find a way to change that behaviour?

Comment: Where did you quote the first paragraph from? Is that even supposed to be a quote?